# How to show value from localstorage in other page?

Tags: javascript, php

I have javascript in page One :

```
<script>
  var valueRm = noRm.value;
  localStorage.setItem("noRm", valueRm);
</script>
```

And this is my javascript in second page :

```
<input id="noRmUser" name="noRmUser"/>

<script>
  var valueRm = localStorage.noRm;

  //i try with 3 ways, but i can't get that value 
   //-->> document.getElementById('noRmUser').value = valueRm;
   //-->> document.getElementById('noRmUser').setAttribute('value', 
          localStorage.getItem('noRm'));
   //-->> document.getElementById('noRmUser').setAttribute('value', 
          localStorage.getItem('valueRm'));

  //but if i show in console, that value can show
  //-->> console.log(valueRm);
```

i want show noRm from page one and show noRm in second page on tag input...

[image]

I start to learn javascript.. Can someone help me?
Very thankyou if someone want to help me :))

Comment: if two pages are same domain `localStorage.getItem` is enough

Comment: @prasanth yes sir, if i show in console i can show that, but i cant to show in tag input. in above i have try with 3 ways, but not show anything. can you help me sir ?

Comment: You’ve demonstrated that the issue is not with local storage if you can see the value in the console. Therefore the issue is the js to add it to the input

Comment: Could this be a case of the Input not being in the dom when the JavaScript runs?  Is the script before the input, or after

Comment: @TimMorton my script just like that, or i must give $(document).ready(function() ..
in javascript second page sir ? but, in console still working to show that value

Comment: @YeruAdi yes, `$(document).ready` is an alternative, or just like @TimMorton said. Just make sure that your script runs after DOM is loaded

Comment: @scott6 yes sir, but it is same. i cant fill value in input tag

Answer (score 0):

**[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/owsf7t2v/1/)**

Before set some value in `input.value` .

```
<input id="noRmUser" name="noRmUser" value="hello"/>
```

For first thing element call was wrong
use

```
 var valueRm = document.getElementById('noRmUser').value;
```

And  `localStorage.noRm;` is one invalid call .get item only use `localStorage.getItem('noRm')`

**For Page 1** : dont forget to add `value="something"` in input element

```
var valueRm = document.getElementById('noRmUser').value;
  localStorage.setItem("noRm", valueRm);
```

**For second Page 2**

```
window.onload = function(){
 document.getElementById('noRmUser').value =localStorage.getItem('noRm')
}
```

Comment: Am I misreading the question? He wants to set the value of the input, not get it.

Comment: yes you are right.Both empty input and dom calling of input element `noRm.value` both are wrong

Comment: @prasanth yes sir, but if i use localStorage.noRm; that is can show in second page, but just in console. how can i show noRm from page one to second page in tag input ?

Comment: @prasanth i not call from element in second page, but i want to fill input element from page one sir.

Comment: @TimMorton yes sir, you right. can you help me sir ?

Comment: Oh I see what you’re saying. It would be helpful to see the solution here, without having to go to the fiddle. Otherwise, it looks completely backwards without the set command :p

Comment: @prasanth yes sir, i can show noRm in alert, but i can't show in tag input :(

Comment: @TimMorton yes sir, i try before to show in alert. but i cant show in tag input.. i confused to show in tag input hahaha

Comment: if you can display it on alert, you can do this also `document.getElementById('noRmUser').value=localStorage.getItem('noRm')`

Comment: Oh, wait. No, the issue is not the local storage. He’s got the local storage (visible in console) but can’t get it to appear in the input.

Comment: @prasanth can you show in tag input sir ? i confused to show in tag input :( 
i try to show in console and alert. but i dont know why,  i cant show in tag input :(

Comment: @scott6 yes sir, but i cant show in tag input. i dont know why :(

Comment: i thing you are using same script for both . Try like `document.getElementById('second').value =localStorage.getItem('noRm');` . set different id name second page input like above

Comment: simply paste the script tag in end of the document .or wrap code with `window.onload = function() { //do stuff }` in second page @YeruAdi.. Check my update

Comment: @prasanth i try to warp code with    window.onload = function() {  ...} 
but still i cant show that value in element tag sir

Comment: are you change the second page input tag id?if not change and try

Comment: its working good for check one by one [first_page](https://jsfiddle.net/owsf7t2v/1/) then [second_page](https://jsfiddle.net/76pzo1jy/1/)  @YeruAdi

Comment: @prasanth still not working sir, i dont know why..
why so hard :(
i try with another code but it is same, not working

Comment: @prasanth i cant post full code in stackoverflow sir.. but that can run if use alert, document.write() and console.log but cant use tag input/ a / p

Answer (score 0):

Your script must come after the input. Page rendering stops when a script tag is encountered and the JavaScript runs immediately.

There is no element in the dom when the script tries to assign it.

Put the script at the bottom of the page, right before the closing body tag

Comment: yes sir, i just confused why value can show in console but cant show in tag input or p or other :(

Comment: Because it doesn’t exist yet when the script runs

Comment: * the input doesn’t exist, that is